# Factory class perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, templates, factory, perfect-forwarding

Consider following code sample:

```
template<class T, class U>
struct b{
    b(T &&, U &&);
    //some useful stuff
};

template<class T>
struct factory{
    factory(T &&arg) : arg_(std::forward<T>(arg)){}

    template<class U>
    auto create(U &&u) const &{
        return b<const T &, U>(arg_, std::forward<U>(u));
    }
    template<class U>
    auto create(U &&u)  &&{
        return b<T, U>(std::forward<T>(arg_), std::forward<U>(u));
    }

    T arg_;
};

template<class T>
auto
make_factory(T &&t){
    return factory<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

I am concerned with code inside `factory` struct - are the `create` methods fastest possible, is it **the best** way to use perfect forwarding with factory classes?

1. Did I miss something or this code is 'perfect' in terms of forwarding/moving data around? I would like to avoid copying wherever it is possible.
2. Should I add/remove const in any of the `create` methods?

EDIT: Due to Your concerns - I am aware that sometimes I will pass lvalue reference and specialize template for it. It is desired behaviour. As I written up there - I want to avoid copying anything unless *really* needed. So factory can store reference if object was created in scope outside of it. I know it is unsafe, but still it is a design choice. For reference factory created object should also store reference. I hope this clarifies most of Your issues.

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass references to template parameters?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yup, I am sure. As I said, I want to avoid copying as much as I can, even if it means storing reference.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether you fully understand what you are doing in the code.

```
template<class T>
auto
make_factory(T &&t){
    return factory<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

This code try to make a factory of `T`. However, if you pass an lvalue to `make_factory()`, `T` will be deduced to a reference. Then you will create a factory of reference. I think this is unlikely your purpose.

And moreover, this one

```
factory(T &&arg) : arg_(std::forward<T>(arg)){}
```

is *not* a forwarding reference, because `T` is not the type name to be deduced in this function.

Comment: Also: I don't know if OP consciously abused `std::forward` to do a `std::move` in the rvalue reference of `create` :P

Comment: I also had some cases to do this trick, but I think in such situation OP will emphasize this point, because this will impact the *behavior* of the program, not just some redundant copy...

Comment: Storing reference is desired behaviour as I would like not to copy anything that is not completely necessary

Comment: @Rakete1111 AFAIK - if I have lvalue reference stored, `forward` is more reasonable than `move` or am I wrong?

Comment: @bartop You need to clarify what you want when you create a factory of reference and when you create a ordinary factory. For me they are quite different cases, and we don't know your intention. As for whether there will be additional copy, it can be easily determined after reading the signature of `std::forward`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

Comment: @liliscent Added a bit of clarification in the question. Hopefully it will help

Comment: @bartop I think there is no redundant copy in your code.

Comment: @bartop Another `non-const` create should be added, otherwise a `non-const` factory can only produce a `struct b` with `const T`.